# Building pie chart map based on square shape, starting with land use soil shape in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, cartography

I'm a beginner and I usually use Qgis. 
I would build a map made by a pie chart pattern, as in the picture attached. The pie chart returns the values in percentage of the land use soil. I would like that the system shows the percentage of the land use coverage in each quadrant of the grid.
E.g.  Square XXX 10% urban, 21% forests etc. for each quadrant.

I decided to do it this way:
1 - I build a grid of squares;
2 - Intersect squares with the use of the soil;
3 - ????

As output result I obtain a shape that is the intersection between the grid of the squares and the geometries of the land use soil.
I don't know how go ahead working.
I need to figure out how to reassemble the square keeping the land-use values.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought using "union" rather than "intersection" would be better, as the grid layer would then contain the soil use polygons for each grid, rather than the soil use layer being split at the grid boundaries.

But if you've calculated the percentages in your soil use layer, then you could use a simple join between the two layers then save the grid to lock the joined columns. Because you used intersection your soil use layer will have the grid ID which you can use to join on.

Open the layer properties of your grid layer and select the "Joins" tab.  At the bottom click "+"

```
Join layer = soil use layer
Join Field = grid ID created from intersection
Target Field = Grid ID
Choose which fields are joined = Check, select all columns with calculated %
```